# Can google chromecast receiver app work without sender app... fed from web server

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromecast

I am currently exploring the possibility of using Chromecast + a custom receiver app instead of a raspberry pi custom code application, or something similar. My goal is to be able to have a Chromecast receiver app pull down various streams/images/text and display them on the TV in some custom layout. If I understand the SDK, the custom receiver html/css/js files would be hosted on my public server, and the chromecast device would pull those down to the device (possibly stored on it?). What I am not quite clear on is if that app can then pull down media files, images, etc and display them, or if the only thing that can be displayed is from a sender app? My concern is we'd like to potentially have 100's of Chromecast devices set up, and using a single server (or possibly a couple) feed the video/image/etc to them individually. In some cases some of the TVs would be used to display the same video/images/text. In other cases they'd be completely separate feeds.

Is it possible to do this, or is this too open ended for what the Chromecast SDK allows for? I am trying to decide if I should look at either custom code on Raspberry Pi with custom code, or if perhaps even something more powerful like the new intel MinnowMax, which I realize is $100, but I need to make sure I can display overlapping graphics, video, text as I want and that I can do so from dozens (or more) devices feeding from a server of mine. One more time, to be clear, I want to store various videos, images, etc on my server, and have them pulled down (and cached) to the local device at a TV to display... so if for example the internet is severed, the device can still display the videos/images/text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, in order to start an application on your chromecast, you would need to have a sender device on the local wifi network to start the app; after it starts, what shows up there on the screen can be anything that your receiver's logic decides; for example your html5 receiver may have instructions to go to Url A and grab Video A and then go to a different Url to get a different image, etc. The main point is that there needs to be a sender to load your application and cannot be done automagically.
- The content of the page is the usual stuff that you support in html5 but that little dongle is not very strong on CPU and memory, hence you won't be able to do things that you would normally do on a desktop browser, or if you try to do, it would not be as slick. Also, you cannot have two concurrently active video elements on the same page.
- In terms of caching, it doesn't cache things for long time and in a addition, its disk space is limited. As a result, you would need to have and maintain a network connection.

Comment: Ok, it's as I suspected.. oh well I'll use the one I bought to test out for other purposes then I guess ;). Thanks for the reply.